# Setting up Model Class and Custom Adapter to get SQLite DB rowID from onListItemClick

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, adapter, rowid

I have an app that populates from a pre-existing SQLite database. I am now in need of obtaining the rowID (_id) when a list item is clicked. I think that I did not set my app up properly to be able to do that. I have had people provide me with input on what to do but I can't seem to understand it when trying to apply it to my app. Can someone please provide an example using my code? I would really appreciate it.

Here is my model class:

```
package com.mypackage.myapp.model;

import android.database.Cursor;

public class Verse {

private Cursor verseCursor;
private String verseNotificationString;
private String verseTitleString;
private int dBrowIdInt;
private String bookNameString;
private String chapterNumberString;
private String verseNumberString;
private String verseString;

public Verse(Cursor cursor, String bookNameString, String chapterNumberString, String verseNumberString, String verseString) {
    verseCursor = cursor;
    verseTitleString = bookNameString + " " + chapterNumberString + ":" + verseNumberString;
    verseNotificationString = verseString;
}

public Verse(int dBrowId) {
    dBrowIdInt = dBrowId;
}

public Cursor getVerseCursor() {
    return verseCursor;
}

public void setVerseCursor(Cursor verseCursor) {
    this.verseCursor = verseCursor;
}

public String getVerseTitleString() {
    return verseTitleString;
}

public String getNotificationString() {
    return verseNotificationString;
}

public Integer getDbRowId() {
    return dBrowIdInt;
}

public void setNotificationString(String notificationString) {
    this.verseNotificationString = notificationString;
}

public void setTitleString(String titleString) {
    this.verseTitleString = titleString;
}
```

}

Here is my custom adapter:

```
    package com.mypackage.myapp;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class VerseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Context mContext;
private int mResource1;
private int mResource2;
public List<String> mVerses;
private List<Long> mRowId;
private TextView mVerseTextView;
private TextView mVerseNumberTextView;
private TextView mRowIdTextView;
private boolean mNightModeSwitchState;
private boolean mNightModeTwoSwitchState;

public VerseAdapter(Context context, int resource1, List<String> 
verses, List<Long> rowId) {
    super(context, resource1, verses);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mResource1 = resource1;
    this.mVerses = verses;
    this.mRowId = rowId;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mVerses.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return (position);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, 
@NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View listItem = convertView;
    int pos = position + 1;
    if (listItem == null) {
        listItem = 
LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(mResource1, parent, false);
    }

    //mRowIdTextView = (TextView) 
listItem.findViewById(R.id.rowId);
//mRowIdTextView.setText(String.valueOf(getItemId(position)));
    //mRowIdTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mRowId.get(position)));

    mVerseNumberTextView = (TextView) 
listItem.findViewById(R.id.verseNumber);
    mVerseNumberTextView.setText(String.valueOf(pos) + " ");

    mVerseTextView = (TextView) 
listItem.findViewById(R.id.verseWords);
    mVerseTextView.setText(mVerses.get(position));

    SharedPreferences nightModeSwitchState = 
getContext().getSharedPreferences("SettingsActivity", 0);
    mNightModeSwitchState = 
nightModeSwitchState.getBoolean("NightModeSwitchState", false);

    SharedPreferences rowPosition = 
getContext().getSharedPreferences("RowPosition", 0);
    rowPosition.edit().putInt("RowPositionSqlite", 
position).apply();

    return listItem;
}
```

}

Here is my onListItemClick mehtod in the class that I need to access the rowID from (You can see some stuff that I tried and didn't work commented out):

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View 
view, int position, long id) {

            String selected = (String) 
mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            mVerseTextView = findViewById(R.id.verseWords);
            mVerseNumberTextView = findViewById(R.id.verseNumber);

            mAdapterView = adapterView;
            mPositionForRow = position;
            //mIdLong = id;
            // VerseAdapter verseAdapter = (VerseAdapter) 
adapterView.getAdapter();
            // mSelectedVerse = (VerseForId) 
mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            // mDbRowId = mSelectedVerse.getDbRowId();

            //  mIdLong = verseAdapter.getItemId(position);

            //  mRowIdString = String.valueOf(id);

            // VerseAdapter da = (VerseAdapter) 
    adapterView.getAdapter();
            //mRowIdString = 
    String.valueOf(da.mVerses.get(position).getId());
            // Toast.makeText(BibleBookVersesOldTestActivity.this, 
    mRowIdString + " id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            mBookCopied = 
mVerseHeaderBookNameTextView.getText().toString();
            mChapterNumberCopied = 
Integer.toString(mChapterSelected + 1);
            mVerseNumberCopied = 
mVerseNumberTextView.getText().toString();
            mPosition = position + 1;
            mCopiedVerseListItem = mBookCopied + " " + 
mChapterNumberCopied + ":" + mPosition + "\n\n" + selected;

            showMenuVerseAction(view);
        }
    });
```

I know that I need to do something in my model class and custom adapter to set it up to be able to retrieve the database rowID onlistitemclick. Can someone possibly give me an example using my code? Thank you for your help.

*******Addition.... this is my Databaseaccess class.... well one section of it where I draw verses from a certain book from the SQLite Database. I have adjusted the other class that populates the list and therefor had to change the below operation to take in the model class Verse instead of String in the list... the problem I have is that the line below that reads list.add(cursor.getString(6)) where the (6) refers to the column index where to pull the verse from... gives an error that I can't apply that getString to Verse... how do I resolve this?

```
public List<Verse> getVersesChapterOne() {
    List<Verse> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM bookcombinedfull 
LIMIT 31", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(6));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to replace the Custom Adapter's list from `String` to your model `Verse`. In this way, you can use the `.getItem()` to retrieve whatever information you want from your model class.

```
// public class VerseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
public class VerseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  public List<String> mVerses;

  // public VerseAdapter(Context context, int resource1, List<String> verses, List<Long> rowId) {
  public VerseAdapter(Context context, int resource1, List<Verse> verses) {
    //...
    mVerses = verses;
    //...

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int i) {
    return (Verse)mList.get(i);
  }

// ...
```

```
// In your MainActivity.java, do this to get your item:

Verse verse = (Verse) mAdapter.getItem(position);
Log.d(TAG, verse.getVerseTitleString());
```

Comment: Thank you very much lurker0152. I have begun to make that adjustment but now a new error has arisen based on those changes... I have edited my question.. can you take a look at it and tell me what you think please? I appreciate your help with this. It's been a stopping point for me for a while.

Comment: Post your logcat details. Use Log.d() to dump the contents of the cursor.getString(x). Change the x value. Are you expecting the expected results? You will find your answers there.

Comment: Thanks again lurker. I meant to say that it gives the error prior to running. It underlines that item in red and and when I hover over it, it says: add(mode.verse) in List cannot be applied to (java.lang.String). I don't think it has to do with the x value. Its not letting me combine Verse and String there.

Comment: The `list.add(cursor.getString(6));` fails because the `list` was declared as `List<Verse> list = new ArrayList<>();`, meant to store a list of objects. To store a list of strings, change to `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`